# Ace editor API for wrapping selection in brackets

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor for writing livescript. Out of the box there is no functionality for automatic wrapping selection in brackets on keypress e.g

[image]

Enabling auto-completion didn't make any diiference, so I've written custom command:

```
    {
      name: "brackets []",
      bindKey: '[',
      exec: function(editor){
        var selection;
        if ((selection = editor.session.getTextRange(editor.getSelectionRange())).length) {
          editor.insert("[" + selection + "]");
        } else {
          editor.insert("[");
        }
      }
    }
```

And it works correctly, but here is a question:

Are there other api buildin ace that could achieve same effect simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this is a bug in the [livescript mode](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/livescript.js#L5) other modes are supporting this by defining [`$behavior` property](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/actionscript.js#L47), but livescript mode misses both behavior and folding rules.

Comment: you are right, a defined `$behavior` in mode file and now it works without custom commands